# MongoDB updating all records in a collection with the results of query from another collection

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have around 40k records to update and each record gets the data from querying another collection.
I have an existing query to do this, but it runs for more than an hour. It usually disconnects, then I rerun it again.
I think there is a better way to do this, I am just a noob with mongodb and this solution works but I am not happy with the execution speed.
Maybe you have a better or much faster solution.

To better illustrate the data, please see below:

**accounts**

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("AC101"),
    "emails":null,
    "name":"Account 101",
    ...
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("AC102"),
    "emails":null,
    "name":"Account 102",
    ...
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("AC103"),
    "emails":null,
    "name":"Account 103",
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```

**account_contacts**

```
[
  {
    "_id": Object("ACC001"),
    "account": {
        "$ref" : "account",
        "$id" : ObjectId("AC101")
    },
    "email":"acc001@test.com",
    "name":"Contact 001",
    ...
  },
  {
    "_id": Object("ACC002"),
    "account": {
        "$ref" : "account",
        "$id" : ObjectId("AC102")
    },
    "email":"acc002@test.com",
    "name":"Contact 002",
    ...
  },
  {
    "_id": Object("ACC003"),
    "account": {
        "$ref" : "account",
        "$id" : ObjectId("AC103")
    },
    "email":"acc003@test.com",
    "name":"Contact 003",
    ...
  },
  {
    "_id": Object("ACC004"),
    "account": {
        "$ref" : "account",
        "$id" : ObjectId("AC103")
    },
    "email":"acc004@test.com",
    "name":"Contact 004",
    ...
  },
  {
    "_id": Object("ACC005"),
    "account": {
        "$ref" : "account",
        "$id" : ObjectId("AC103")
    },
    "email":"acc005@test.com",
    "name":"Contact 005",
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```

**Query:**

```
db.getCollection('accounts').find({ 'emails':{ $eq:null } }).forEach(p => {
    const emails = [];
    db.getCollection('account_contacts').find({"account.$id": p._id}).forEach(c => {
        emails.push(c.email);
    });
    db.getCollection('accounts').updateOne({"_id": p._id}, {$set: {"emails": emails}});
});
```

I have a filter to get only the accounts with null `emails`, so that if it gets a timeout error (1hr)... I just rerun the script and it will process those accounts with null emails.

Currently, I do not have any idea on how to improve the query... but I know it is not the best solution for this case since it takes more than an hour.

**Update:**

While I still cannot make the aggregate/lookUp approach work, I did tried to run the old script in mongo console, which I ran before and executes more than an hour in my ID... If you run it directly in the mongo console, it only takes 12-14 mins which is not bad.

This is what I did for now, but I still want to convert my script to use aggregation.

TIA

Comment: Which version of MongoDB?

Comment: I am using version 4.2.3

Comment: Does this field `"account.$id"` really contain a `$`, or was that supposed to be `"account._id"?

Comment: While searching, I scanned something about bulk update in mongo, I will check it and see if I can convert my query using bulk update unordered.

Comment: yes id contains `account.$id` it is a dbref pointing to the `account._id`

Answer (score 3):

Using MongoDB 4.2, you can avoid pulling the documents to the client side if you are willing to use a temporary collection.

Use aggregation to match all of the documents with null email, extract just the _id and store it in a temporary collection.  Note that if you have an index on `{emails:1, _id:1}` it will streamline this part.  You may want to procedurally generate the temporary collection name so it doesn't use the same name for successive runs.

```
db.accounts.aggregate([
    {$match: {emails: null}},
    {$project: {_id: 1}},
    {$out: "temporary_null_email_collection"}
])
```

Then aggregate the temporary collection, lookup the email from the account_contacts collection, get rid of any extraneous fields, and merge the results back with the accounts collection.

```
db.temporary_null_email_collection.aggregate([
    {$lookup:{
         from: "account_contacts",
         localField: "_id",
         foreignField: "$id", // verify this field name is correct
         as: contacts
    }},
    {$project: {
          _id: 1,
          emails: "$contacts.emails"
    }},
    {$merge: "accounts"}
])
```

Comment: clarification .. the `index {emails:1, _id:1}` ... this is on `accounts` collection? I checked, only one index `_id` in `accounts`. In `account_contacts` ... `email` and `_id` is indexed.

Comment: Yes, if you have that index on the accounts collection, the first aggregation will not have to read nearly as much data.

Comment: I tried this, but for `accounts.emails` I only got empty `[]` for all the records in `accounts`. I used `foreignField: "account.id"` ... It does not accept `foreignField: "account.$id"`.

Comment: There is a possibility that there will be multiple emails per account, I want these emails be grouped as array like `[ "aaa@aaa.com", "bbb@bbb.com", "ccc@ccc.com" ]`.

Comment: {
 "$clusterTime" : {
  "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1591621365, 1),
  "signature" : {
   "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
   "keyId" : 0
  }
 },
 "code" : 16410,
 "codeName" : "Location16410",
 "message" : "FieldPath field names may not start with '$'.",
 "name" : "MongoError",
 "ok" : 0,
 "operationTime" : Timestamp(1591621365, 1)
}

Comment: This is the error I am getting if I use `$` in `foreignField: "account.$id"`. If we base the sample data (structure) above.. `account.$id` is a db reference to `accounts._id`

Comment: btw, this is how `account_contacts.account` looks like `"account": DBRef("account", ObjectId("AC103"))`. I want to match `temporary_null_email_collection._id` with `account.$id` in the look up.. but I cannot make it work.